# BBC.co.uk style jquery slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-slider

Does anybody know where I can find a jquery slider like the one on the new http://www.bbc.co.uk  website. Not interested in the actual functionality within the slide itself (IE. All the images and links within the slide). It's the full screen looping carousel type effect I'm after, with navigation.

Comment: Why "like"? You can use [the same plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jcarousel) as they're using - unless you think they tweaked it somehow?

Comment: It's more a Content Slider as opposed to an actual carousel.... although I could be wrong.

Comment: Actually Shadow Wizard, you might well be right. I've been using jCarousel for a while and I've not yet tried using it as a "content slider". Might be just the job. Thanks.

Comment: Hi guys. How can I set this question as answered if people have only posted comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bbc website is actually using a custom javascript library called [glow](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/). you might want to look at [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/):

Alternatively you can also use this [slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

Comment: Interesting...it's the first time I've seen the "Glow" library.

Answer (score 2):

The example at http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/ looks very much like the BBC version and uses this plugin: http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.paulwelsh.info/jquery-plugins/hero-carousel/ - This is quite a simple version & Responsive too!

Hopefully this'll help. Unfortunately, it's not very well documented, but some kind guy on SO has created a fiddle at [Problems implenting Hero Carousel Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768082/problems-implenting-hero-carousel-slider)

Comment: the slider/swiper is not fully responsive